# Printing line from text file according to line location

Tags: c#, list, location

I cannot find anything specific enough to help me out so going to give asking a try. So basically I'm trying to print the lines from a text file but only the ones on specific lines. I used a for statement and added the line location to a list element but how do i take these numbers & use them as line locations to print out something else from another text file?

```
  case "January":
                        for (int i = 0; i < 599; i++)
                        {
                            if (Month_1[i].Contains("January"))
                            {
                                List<int> list = new List<int>();
                                list.Add(i);

                                Console.WriteLine("Location: " + string.Join("\n", list));

                            }


                        }
                        break;
```

If you do not understand what I want here is a break down. One file is full of months and I am looking for "January", the line location of January is important because there are multiple other text file and everyone on the same line as January will go together when I print them all out.

January is on line 10 in my months file, line 10 in my day file will correspond with January and they'll both be printed but lines 1-9 will not.

Answer (score 0):

> So basically I'm trying to print the lines from a text file but only the ones on specific lines

Once you have your file in a string format, you can just split it on the "\n" symbol and get a list of strings which represent the lines.

From there just run on it and select the line number using a loop(or any other way of selecting via something like LINQ).

Comment: Hey thank you for taking your time to answer. Could you be a little bit more specific? The line numbers are already stored in the list statement by the code above, how do I take these numbers and use them as positions to print from other text files?

Comment: Once you open your file in C# and read it, you get a byte array. Convert that byte array to a string, and then use the Split function on that with the "\n" symbol to receive an array with each line being a separate string in the new array. Just having the line numbers is probably not very helpful, or at least I do not know of a way to navigate through a file via line numbers.